# Couchdb Update/Replace replication filter

Tags: c#, xamarin, couchdb, database-replication, couchbase-lite

Is there any way of update/replace the filter of a pull replication?
I'm stopping the replication, setting the new filter and start the replication. 
I've tried with restart too...

BTW, i'm purging the documents that i don't need before changing the filter.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the safest way would be to create a new pull replication with a different filter.

Comment: The problem is, even if I close the app I can't get those documents. I can only get them again when i delete the app or when I delete the database of the app. I think the problem is related with the purge of the document. But, on the couchbase lite documentation - http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html#purging-a-document- you can see " if you purge a document, and then later the document is updated on the remote server, the next replication will pull the document into your database". I tried that, not luck too...

Comment: You are going to have to put up the relevant source code for your project then, because I cannot understand what you are attempting to do.  Purging documents is not something that you do if you expect to have the documents back again at some point.  The next replication pulling the document is a side effect, but it is not a feature.